# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute when seeding belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to seed a has_many/belongs_to relationship.
A user has_many scripts, a script belongs_to a user.

When seeding the script, I get this error:

> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for
>   Script.

I'd think that this line in my migration would create a user_id attribute for script?

```
t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

*app/models/script.rb*

```
class Script < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :commits
  has_many :script_users, through: :commits, source: :user
end
```

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scripts
  has_many :used_scripts, through: :commits, source: :script
  has_many :commits
end
```

*db/migrate/20171231022826_create_scripts.rb*

```
class CreateScripts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :scripts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :skill
      t.string :bot_for
      t.string :game_for

      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*db/seeds.rb*

```
admin = User.create!(
  email: 'a@a.com',
  password: 'adminadmin',
  password_confirmation: 'adminadmin'
)

script = Script.create!(
  name: 'YWoodcutter',
  skill: 'Woodcutting',
  bot_for: 'Android',
  game_for: "CandyLand,
  user_id: admin.id
)
```

> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for
>   Script.
>   I've made sure to rake:db reset and still get error.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I did a few things and it's working OK now. I believe the issue may have been that my user migration was created after my script migration. The user migration should done before scripts, so I changed the dates to change the order they were migrated in. Did a rake rake db:rollback & db:reset for good measure too.

Comment: Do you have `user_id` in commits table ?

Answer (score 1):

`belongs_to` is an alias of `reference` and it should work same as `references`

If its not working for you just try with following solution

```
class CreateScripts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :scripts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :skill
      t.string :bot_for
      t.string :game_for

      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah I learned that while researching this :)
I just tried t.references and am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you please try this in `rails console` `User.last.scripts`, let me know what its returning.

Comment: I get an error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column scripts.user_id does not exist

Comment: Its strange!, it should be work, can you please rollback this migration and try again?

Comment: I did a few things and it's working OK now. I believe the issue may have been that my user migration was created after my script migration. THe user migration should be done before scripts, so I changed the dates to change the order they were migrated in. Did a rake rake db:rollback & db:reset for good measure too.Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Great!, Yes when you are refering any model it should be exist there.

Answer (score 0):

Create Model with below line

```
rails g model script references:user
```

It will by default below line in migration file

```
t.references :user, foreign_key: true
```

and add `belongs_to :user` in script model . It might be `t.references :user` in rails 5 not `t.belongs_to :user`

Comment: This is what I had originally, thanks. I manage to solve it somehow, updated OP with details.